# Why does my website become left aligned on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

[My website](https://explorar.neocities.org/mobile.html) becomes left aligned on mobile, but (the mobile version) looks fine on the desktop. I have tried messing around with a few things, but at this point I give up.

[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY9gI.png) && [Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uarx.png)

I am also having an issue where when the page initially loads elements are out of place, but when you refresh the page they get fixed; bonus points if you can fix this issue!

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    
    <title>ᘿ᙭ᕵᒪᓍᖇᗩᖇ</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
    <link href="mobileStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body onresize="resized()">
<div class="clipped-wrap">
    <p class="clipped">ExplorAR</p>
</div>
<div id="inksplatter" onClick="imageEnlarge('inksplatter','image',0,'Sinister Comfort')" style="z-index: 6; top: 180px;">
    <div class="splat" style="background: url(portfolio/inksplatter-min.png); background-size: cover;"></div>
</div>
<div id="abuse" onClick="imageEnlarge('abuse','video',1,'Abuse (Addixtion 2021)')" style="z-index: 6; top: 270px; animation-delay: 0.8s;">
    <div class="splat" style="background: url(portfolio/abuse-min.gif); background-size: cover; animation-delay: 0.8s;"></div>
</div>
<div id="alone" onClick="imageEnlarge('alone','video',2,'Alone (Addixtion 2021)')" style="z-index: 6; top: 400px; animation-delay: 0.4s;">
    <div class="splat" style="background: url(portfolio/alone-min.gif); background-size: cover;  animation-delay: 0.4s;"></div>
</div>
<div id="barf" onClick="imageEnlarge('barf','video',3,'BARF2FEELBETTER (Addixtion 2021)')" style="z-index: 6; top: 520px; animation-delay: 1.2s">
    <div class="splat" style="background: url(portfolio/barf-min.gif); background-size: cover;  animation-delay: 1.2s"></div>
</div>
<div id="happy" onClick="imageEnlarge('happy','video',4,'Happys Pills (Addixtion 2021)')" style="z-index: 6; top: 650px; animation-delay: 0.8s">
    <div class="splat" style="background: url(portfolio/happy-min.gif); background-size: cover;  animation-delay: 0.8s"></div>
</div>
<div id="identity" onClick="imageEnlarge('identity','video',5,'Identity (Addixtion 2021)')" style="z-index: 6; top: 780px; animation-delay: 1.2s">
    <div class="splat" style="background: url(portfolio/identity-min.gif); background-size: cover;  animation-delay: 1.6s"></div>
</div>
<div id="lost" onClick="imageEnlarge('thea','image',6,'Lost')" style="z-index: 6; top: 910px; animation-delay: 1.6s">
    <div class="splat" style="background: url(portfolio/thea-min.png); background-size: cover;  animation-delay: 1.2s"></div>
</div>
<div id="death" onClick="imageEnlarge('Death','image',7,'Death, Disease, and Pestillence')" style="z-index: 6; top: 1050px; animation-delay: 2s">
    <div class="splat" style="background: url(portfolio/Death-min.png); background-size: cover; animation-delay: 2s"></div>
</div>
<img id="BG" src="mobileElement.png" style="position: absolute; margin:0px; top: -140px;">
<a href="/blog.html" class="externalLinks" style="position: absolute; top: 1250px; left: 32%;">Blog</a>
<a href="/videoGames.html" class="externalLinks" style="position: absolute; top: 1350px; left: 22%;">V.Games</a>
<a href="/WIP.html" class="externalLinks" style="position: absolute; top: 1450px; left: 32%;">WIP</a>
</body>
<script src="mobile.js"></script>
</html>
```

**JS**

(**The important information for alignment is here at the top**, you can ignore the trigger for the funtion, it just triggers once all images are loaded. This was my attempt to fix my loading issue, but it does not work)

```
    var img = document.querySelector('img')

function loaded() {
  document.getElementById('BG').style.left = (window.innerWidth/2 - document.getElementById('BG').width/2) + "px";
var BGbox = document.getElementById('BG').getBoundingClientRect();
document.getElementById('inksplatter').style.left = BGbox.left + 190 + "px";
document.getElementById('abuse').style.left = BGbox.left + 45 + "px";
document.getElementById('alone').style.left = BGbox.left + 170 + "px";
document.getElementById('barf').style.left = BGbox.left + 50 + "px";
document.getElementById('happy').style.left = BGbox.left + 190 + "px";
document.getElementById('identity').style.left = BGbox.left + 50 + "px";
document.getElementById('lost').style.left = BGbox.left + 190 + "px";
document.getElementById('death').style.left = BGbox.left + 60 + "px";
}

if (img.complete) {
  loaded()
} else {
  img.addEventListener('load', loaded)
  img.addEventListener('error', function() {
      alert('error')
  })
}

function resized() {
    document.getElementById('BG').style.left = (window.innerWidth/2 - document.getElementById('BG').width/2) + "px";
    var BGbox = document.getElementById('BG').getBoundingClientRect();
    document.getElementById('inksplatter').style.left = BGbox.left + 190 + "px";
    document.getElementById('abuse').style.left = BGbox.left + 45 + "px";
    document.getElementById('alone').style.left = BGbox.left + 170 + "px";
    document.getElementById('barf').style.left = BGbox.left + 50 + "px";
    document.getElementById('happy').style.left = BGbox.left + 190 + "px";
    document.getElementById('identity').style.left = BGbox.left + 50 + "px";
    document.getElementById('lost').style.left = BGbox.left + 190 + "px";
    document.getElementById('death').style.left = BGbox.left + 60 + "px";
};

var descArray = ["Inspired by 'The Laughing Man, Ghost In The Shell' but remixed with grunge and glitch art elements; I am a huge fan of sinister smiles",
                 "Abuse has an addictive property that most people do not mention. When two adults engage in an abusive relationship, both the abuser and abused must get something out of the relationship in order for the abuse to continue. It is heaven and hell, full of highs and lows. It can provide relief from emptinesses caused early in life. There is a certain comfort in an abusive relathionship if it is all you have known.",
                 "The mind is not meant for isolation, but many of us have afflictions that make it difficult to socialize. This turbulent cycle of wanting to isolate, but hurting as a result of it is very similar to (and often the cause of) hard drug addictions. This is a cycle that gets worse with time.",
                 "When you come out of a bender the withdrawal can hit hard. Intense vomiting and nausea are the first signs of what you truly have done to yourself. The second signs are the knowledge of what horrible things you have done. You can look down into your vomit reflection and see yourself transformed into a demon.",
                 "Making happiness the only acceptable emotion to feel can be the fuel to continually chase different highs. Never allowing yourself to feel the pain of the past, present, or future does not allow you to heal and process what issues truly ail you. The need to avoid pain will lead to sedation when happiness is no longer a choice, and eventually a loss of self.",
                 "Hiding your true identity and putting on masks to appeal to others can be extremely comforting. It is what we learn to do very early on as children to avoid being bullied. It takes introspection and lots of time to truly find who you are and be comfortable with it. The dissonance between who you are and how you represent yourself can lead to years of shame and embarrassment, causing all sort of self-harm and self-hatred. This can then lead to even more discomfort with being genuine.",
                 "A woman, obscured by the overwhelming distractions of the world.",
                 "I beleive that all good things come from bad, so I like to visually show this by making terrible, scary, or morbid things 'cute.' Here three of The Four Horsemen of The Apocalypse are depicted reflecting this ideal."];

function imageEnlarge(name,type,number,realName){
    var newDom = document.createElement('div');
    newDom.id = "imageWrapper";
    newDom.style.top = window.visualViewport.pageTop + "px";
    document.body.prepend(newDom);
    
    var newDom = document.createElement('div');
    newDom.id = "blackground";
    document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    
    var newDom = document.createElement('img');
    newDom.id = "x";
    newDom.src = "X.png"
    document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    
    if (type == 'image'){
        var newDom = document.createElement('img');
        newDom.id = "bigImage";
        newDom.src = "portfolio/"+name+".png";
        document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    } else {
        var newDom = document.createElement('video');
        newDom.id = "bigImage";
        newDom.loop = "true";
        newDom.autoplay = "true";
        newDom.muted = "true";
        newDom.src = "portfolio/"+name+".mp4";
        document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    }
    var newDom = document.createElement('br');
    document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    
    var newDom = document.createElement('br');
    document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    
    var newDom = document.createElement('paragraph');
    newDom.id = "imageTitle";
    newDom.innerHTML = realName;
    document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    
    var newDom = document.createElement('br');
    document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    
    var newDom = document.createElement('br');
    document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    
    var newDom = document.createElement('paragraph');
    newDom.id = "imageDesc";
    newDom.innerHTML = descArray[number];
    document.getElementById('imageWrapper').append(newDom);
    
    document.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
        document.getElementById('imageWrapper').style.top = window.visualViewport.pageTop + "px";
    })
    
    document.getElementById('x').addEventListener("click", event => {
        document.getElementById('imageWrapper').remove();
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help and the time!

Comment: I think you would have an easier time managing mobile and desktop positioning using CSS media queries. You can define different styles based on screen width and the browser will be responsive without the need for javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I am not utilizing Javascript to handle separate stylings for mobile and desktop, this page is my mobile page. I only mention how it looks on desktop because that is how I edit my websites. All of the css and javascript this page utilizes is for mobile only.

Answer (score 0):

When the page is first loaded the initial-scale property controls the initial zoom level i.e. 1 Viewport pixel = 1 CSS pixel. User-scalable, maximum-scale and minimum-scale properties control how the user is able to zoom the page in or out

So you need to update your viewport meta tag like below -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote, but I am a noob and can not

Comment: No worries, glad that helped !!